# Powermac G4 Booting Up to White Screen?

Tags: macos, boot, osx-tiger, g4, white-screen

I have a Powermac G4 that I use as a server. Since yesterday, for any reason, it chimes, and just goes to a white screen. The only way to make it work again is to reset the PMU by holding the button inside for 10 seconds. It is running 10.4.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly likely a problem with the battery on the logic board, according to [this document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25572?viewlocale=en_US) on Apple's support website.
Be sure to identify the Powermac model next time though! :)